# TFS Build single folder not being copied

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

when building my app on a TFS server, a single folder (with 2 .xml files) aren't copied to the output folder, but all others are.

These files are: a normal xml file and it's tranform version,

This is on the corporate TFS build server and it works for all other files / transformations. So it must be one of my settings in this project / File.

I've checked the files, it's set the same as a .css file that is getting copied (so set to content)

anyone has an idea where I could have a look to find why this is happening?
or even better has a solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that WIX was removing this file